# JAXB - Add a node to the XML as html link

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have a basic JavaBean in my service layer and originally it was not designed for marshalling.  This object is used by both JAX-WS, JAX-RS, and Servlets in other layers of my application.  I want to take advantage of a drill down type effect in my REST services so my question is:  How do I make one of the fields/properties of the javabean appear in the xml as an HTML Link?  Obviously I need to use CData.  I cannot modify the original javabean by adding fields, etc.  Is there an annotation I can use?

If I have in my class:

```
...
String data;
...
```

how do I make that(in xml):

```
<data><![CDATA[<a href="somearbitrarylink">ValueOfData</a>]]></data>
```

is this possible with JAXB and Annotations? Maybe xlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a type adapter. These are normally used to adapt XML string values into more strongly-typed values like timestamps, but you can also use them to adapt strings to strings.

First, create a subclass of `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter`. This class will have to implement `marshal` and `unmarshal`, converting to and from the value of your field, and the HTML fragment in the XML.

Once you have that, you can annotate your field with

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
```

And that should be it.